# How to do hypot2(x,y) calculation when numbers can overflow

Tags: math

I'd like to do a hypot2 calculation on a 16-bit processor.

The standard formula is `c = sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))`. The problem with this is with large inputs it overflows. E.g. 200 and 250, multiply 200 * 200 to get 90,000 which is higher than the max signed value of 32,767, so it overflows, as does b, the numbers are added and the result may as well be useless; it might even signal an error condition because of a negative sqrt.

In my case, I'm dealing with 32-bit numbers, but 32-bit multiply on my processor is very fast, about 4 cycles. I'm using a dsPIC microcontroller. I'd rather not have to multiply with 64-bit numbers because that's wasting precious memory and undoubtedly will be slower. Additionally I only have sqrt for 32-bit numbers, so 64-bit numbers would require another function. So how can I compute a hypot when the values may be large?

Please note I can only really use integer math for this. Using anything like floating point math incurs a speed hit which I'd rather avoid. My processor has a fast integer/fixed point atan2 routine, about 130 cycles; could I use this to compute the hypotenuse length?

Comment: "My processor has a fast integer/fixed point atan2 routine, about 130 cycles; could I use this to compute the hypotenuse length" dsPIC has an atan2 but not a hypot?! I'm vaguely familiar w/ PICs & I'm surprised to hear it.

Comment: @Jason S it is a fixed point software routine.

Comment: Could you post a link to their software routine? If it's CORDIC-related, you get both the angle and the radius out of the same routine.

Comment: @Jason S, it's part of the Microchip 16-bit fixed point library. It is composed of lots of assembly code and it's Microchip copyrighted, so I can't post it here (although it is free, but it can only be used with Microchip MCUs and DSPs.) I think it does use CORDIC, it has a lookup table and uses shifts/adds.

Comment: I didn't mean post it here, I mean post a link to it here. Presumably it's somewhere on their website.

Comment: @Jason S: http://www.microchip.com/Microchip.WWW.SecureSoftwareList/secsoftwaredownload.aspx?device=en010065&lang=en&ReturnURL=http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010065#, you want "16-Bit Language Tools Libraries".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much accuracy you need you may be able to avoid the squares and the square root operation. There is a section on this topic in [Understanding Digital Signal Processing by Rick Lyons](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131089897) (section 10.2, *"High-Speed Vector-Magnitude Approximation"*, starting at page 400 in my edition).

The approximation is essentially:

```
magnitude = alpha * min + beta * max
```

where max and min are the maximum and minimum absolute values of the real and imaginary components, and alpha and beta are two constants which are chosen to give a reasonable error distribution over the range of interest. These constants can be represented as fractions with power of 2 divisors to keep the arithemtic simple/efficient. In the book he suggests alpha = 15/16, beta = 15/32, and you can then simplify the formula to:

```
magnitude = (15 / 16) * (max + min / 2)
```

which might be implemented as follows using integer operations:

```
magnitude = 15 * (max + min / 2) / 16
```

and of course we can use shifts for the divides:

```
magnitude = (15 * (max + (min >> 1))) >> 4
```

Error is +/- 5% over a quadrant.

More information on this technique here: http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/magnitude-estimator

Comment: I'm not dropping £50 on a book right now (poor student here), any hints from your edition?

Comment: @Thomas O: I've added some detail to the answer above.

Comment: I've seen something similar using ~0.91 for alpha and ~0.414 for beta. I guess I could do this with pure integer math, which would be desirable. It would limit me to 2^27 but that's okay for my application.

Comment: this might speed up that calculation by avoiding the sqrt, but it sacrifices much more accuracy than is necessary to avoid the overflow issue in question.  For example, one could just truncate the numbers, since, say, truncating a 32 bit number to 16 bits, only loses roughly 1/2^15 in accuracy = 0.00003 = 0.003%.

Answer (score 3):

This is taken verbatim from [this @John D. Cook blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/02/whats-so-hard-about-finding-a-hypotenuse/), hence CW:

> Here’s how to compute `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`
>   without risking overflow.
>
> 1. `max = maximum(|x|, |y|)`
> 2. `min = minimum(|x|, |y|)`
> 3. `r = min / max`
> 4. `return max*sqrt(1 + r*r)`

If @John D. Cook comes along and posts this you should give him the accept :)

Comment: @Mark Ransom that could be a problem then.

Answer (score 2):

Since you essentially can't do any multiplications without overflow you're likely going to lose some precision.

To get the numbers into an acceptable range, pull out some factor `x` and use

```
c = x*sqrt( (a/x)*(a/x) + (b/x)*(b/x) )
```

If `x` is a common factor, you won't lose precision, but if it's not, you will lose precision.

**Update:**
Even better, given that you can do some mild work with 64-bit numbers, with just one 64-bit addition, you could do the rest of this problem in 32-bits with only a tiny loss of accuracy.  To do this: do the two 32-bit multiplications to give you two 64-bit numbers, add these, and then bit shift as needed to get the sum back down to 32-bits before taking the square root.  If you always bit shift by 2 bits, then just multiply the final result by 2^(half the number of bit shifts), based on the rule above.  The truncation should only cause a very small loss of accuracy, no more than 2^31, or 0.00000005% error.

Answer (score 1):

Aniko and John, it seems to me that you haven't addressed the OP's problem. If a and b are integers, then a*a + b*b is likely to overflow, because integer operations are being performed. The obvious solution is to convert a and b to floating-point values before computing a*a + b*b. But the OP hasn't let us know what language we should use, so we're a bit stuck.

Comment: No hardware FPU; it would add an extra 500-1000 cycles to my currently very fast 100 cycle hypot2 (which works with small numbers.) The obvious solution is not to use floating point, because it's a microcontroller.

Comment: 16-bit processors aren't likely to have performant floating point operations.

Comment: I'm using C, but a general solution is preferred.

Comment: TonyK:  It sounded like he wanted to keep the integer calculations since they were fast.  But your way does avoid the overflow.

Comment: I want to keep the integer ops where possible. FPU is software only, so is quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

> The standard formula is c = sqrt((a * a) + (b * b)). The problem with this is with large >inputs it overflows.

The solution for overflows (aside from throwing an error) is to saturate your intermediate calculations.

Calculate C = a*a + b*b. If a and b are signed 16-bit numbers, you will never have an overflow. If they are unsigned numbers, you'll need to right-shift the inputs first to get the sum to fit in a 32-bit number.

If C > (MAX_RADIUS)^2, return MAX_RADIUS, where MAX_RADIUS is the maximum value you can tolerate before encounting an overflow.

Otherwise, use either sqrt() or the [CORDIC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), which avoids the cost of square roots in favor of loop iteration + adds + shifts, to retrieve the amplitude of the (a,b) vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you can constrain a and b to be at most 7 bits, you won't get any overflow.  You can use a count-leading-zeros instruction to figure out how many bits to throw away.

Assume a>=b.

```
int bits = 16 - count_leading_zeros(a);
if (bits > 7) {
  a >>= bits - 7;
  b >>= bits - 7;
}
c = sqrt(a*a + b*b);
if (bits > 7) {
  c <<= bits - 7;
}
```

Lots of processors have this instruction nowadays, and if not, you can use other [fast techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791878/finding-n-contiguous-zero-bits-in-an-integer-to-the-left-of-the-msb-position-of-a).

Although this won't give you the exact answer, it will be very close (at most ~1% low).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need full precision?  If you don't, you can increase your range a little bit by discarding a few least significant bits and multiplying them in afterwards.

Can `a` and `b` be anything?  How about a lookup table if you only have a few `a` and `b` that you need to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to avoid overflow is to divide both `a` and `b` by `a+b` before squaring, and then multiply the square root by `a+b`. Or do the same with `max(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little simple algebra to bring the results back into range.

```
sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))
= 2 * sqrt(((a * a) + (b * b)) / 4)
= 2 * sqrt((a * a) / 4 + (b * b) / 4)
= 2 * sqrt((a/2 * a/2) + (b/2 * b/2))
```

Comment: This reduces the chance of overflow slightly, but doesn't eliminate it. Dividing by 2 makes an integer use one fewer bit. Squaring doubles the number of bits. You can also throw an abs around a and b, which shaves off a bit (almost) So if `b` is 32 bits, `abs(b)/2` is 30 bits. Squaring that gives us 60 bits, still way more than 32. If the inputs could be kept smaller than +/-131072 this could work, though.

Comment: @Laurence, the divisor could be raised to any arbitrary amount necessary to keep the intermediate values in range. The math remains the same.

Comment: Sure, but for it to work with arbitrary 32 bit numbers that means you need to divide by 65536. That's quite a loss of precision. I suppose you could be adaptive about it: shift the numbers right until they both fit in 16 bits, and then shift the result back in the end, but once it gets that complicated I have to wonder if it's really cheaper than just using 64 bit math.